# OpenERP 7 calendar view reset position of an event upon failed validation

Tags: calendar, odoo

I have a calendar view where the user can move events around. The calendar view is configured to operate on two fields date_min and date_max. These fields are modified inside the object when user moves the appointment around.

However, these fields are also defined to use a constraint that restricts them to a subset of values. I have managed to get the client to display an error if the user moves an object to a new position, but I was not able to get the calendar view to reset the position of the moved object when a move results in an error.

How do I do this?

Instead, what happens is that the appointment stays on the new errornous position in the calendar view, but the fields in the object are not updated still. So the appointment in the calendar view only returns to the correct position when the user resets the calendar view.